# iphone app crashes when location services are toggled

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I have an app which uses location services. 
in my appdelegate i am initializing my location manager property

```
if(self.locationManager == nil)
    {
        self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];  // allocate cllocationmanager property
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;  // confirm the delegate 
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];  // start updating for location 
    }
```

and the location manager delegate is made nil in dealloc method

```
- (void)dealloc
{
   [_window release];
   [_viewController release];

 // [locationManager release];
   self.locationManager.delegate = nil;
   [super dealloc];
}
```

the app crashes 1 out of 10 times when i toggle location services from settings

After debugging in instruments , this is the error displayed

[image]

Kindly suggest the fix for the same .

Comment: How is the locationManager property declared?  What _method_ in the app delegate is locationManager initialized?  Is this the only CLLocationManager declared in the app?

Comment: it is called from - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application and - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

Comment: this is the log i get from organizer - console -  com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.neebal.Demo[0x51ec]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
Jul 20 18:06:56  backboardd[26] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.neebal.Demo[0x51ec]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11

Comment: what delegate methods are you implementing? some of them are deprecated in iOS6. 
for example: 
`- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
     fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation `

Answer (score 0):

create a instance variable if you already haven't that is the same name as your cllocationmanager property and only call self.locationmanager when you are setting as shown here

```
   if (nil == locationManager){
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        startLocation = nil;
    }
```

this is written for arc so add your autorelease if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You've not told the `locationManager` to `stopUpdatingLocation` - [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLLocationManager)